# UIView frame.width is incorrect correct size (on iOS 6 devices)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, ios6

We are trying to programmatically add a UIView (FB Like button) to our game's main view on iOS (* The game is built using Unity).

The code for adding the like button:

```
like = [[FBLikeControl alloc] init];

// Calculate position.

int screenWidth = UnityGetGLViewController().view.bounds.size.width;
int screenHeight = UnityGetGLViewController().view.bounds.size.height;

int likeWidth = like.frame.size.width;
int likeHeight = like.frame.size.height;

int xPos = screenWidth - likeWidth;
int yPos = screenHeight - likeHeight;

like.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, likeWidth, likeHeight);

[UnityGetGLViewController().view addSubview:like];
```

On most devices we've tested this works well, and displays the button in the correct position (bottom right corner).

On a few iOS devices (running iOS 6), the button is cut. It looks like its **frame.width equals to exactly 0.5 (half) of its correct size!** but only the width...

What could be the reason for that ? Is this some known bug with iOS 6 or specific devices ? or is our code not correct ?

Comment: What is the value for `width` you were seeing? And are you sure that you did not confuse `frame` with `bounds`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to construct the button using the **initWithFrame:** method, and provide a fix width and height for it. 
I know it's not the best answer, but I looked into the class, and it has code that should calculate it's size when you don't provide one. There is the possibility that there is a bug in this code, but I don't know for sure.

Some last words of advice : you should retrieve frame information by using the helper methods in CGGeometry.h : (CGRectGetHeight(), CGRectGetWidth(), CGRectGetMinX(), CGRectGetMinY(). Using CGFloat in case of int is also a good idea from my point of view.  )

```html
CGFloat screenWidth = CGRectGetWidth(UnityGetGLViewController().view.bounds);
CGFloat screenHeight = CGRectGetHeight(UnityGetGLViewController().view.bounds)

CGFloat likeWidth = CGRectGetWidth(like.frame);
CGFLoat likeHeight = CGRectGetHeight(like.frame);
```